# call out one index from a List <String>

Tags: java, date, arraylist, indexing, jtable

how can i call out one string from this List i try using the get(index) but it will send an error

```
List<String> strlist = new ArrayList<String>();
strlist.add(datelist);
String[] strarray = strlist.toArray(new String[0]);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strarray));
table_4.setValueAt(strlist.get(1), 0, 0);
```

the String is from a while statement :

```
while (cal2.getTime().before(newDateString)) {
cal2.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
String datelist=(format.format(cal2.getTime()));
```

**The string/output will be like this :**

```
[May 10, 2013]

[May 11, 2013]

[May 12, 2013]

[May 13, 2013]

[May 14, 2013]

[May 15, 2013]

[May 16, 2013]

[May 17, 2013]

[May 18, 2013]
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: the first string is printed:                                      [May 02, 2013]
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
 at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
 at q$8$1.actionPerformed(q.java:965)

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be adding only one element, and the first index of a `List` is 0, so your code should be:

```
table_4.setValueAt(strlist.get(0), 0, 0);
```

For your information, `List` has a nice `toString()` method, so you can use `System.out.println(strlist);` if you do not need the array for anything else.

Another small detail, you can use `strlist.toArray(new String[strlist.size()])` to avoid allocating a new array.

Edit:

```
for (int y = 0 ; y < strlist2.size() ; y++)
{ 
  //This will set the strin at pos y at the y pos in the table.
  table_4.seValue(strlist2.get(y),y,0);
}
```

Comment: I'm doing this because i'm going to output every string in a single cell in a JTable.

Comment: i was able to fill up the row that i want in the JTable, but only one string from my ArrayList is used to fill up the rows.  how can i fill up the Jtable using all the strings from my ArrayList?  here is my current work :                  Iterator itr = strlist2.iterator();
                         while(itr.hasNext()) {
                           Object element = itr.next();
                           int y=0;
                           for (y=0; y <=16 ; ++y){
                         table_4.setValueAt(element, y, 0);
                        }

Comment: Can you edit your question with the code, it will be easier to read. From what I see, you are setting the value `element` 17 times, from (0,0) to (16,0), and then you overwrite this value with another element. I think it should be `for {int y = 0 ; y < strlist2.size() ; y++) { table_4.seValue(strlist2.get(y),y,0);}`, but that's a guess, what is *16* representing, the size of the list?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm just new here :D i want to set the value element 15 times only and yes i want to get the next string from the list and set it to the Jtable, basically i want to fill the (0,0) to (16,0) with the String list. yes the size of the list and  number of rows which is equal

Comment: to summarize my problem all i want is how to call out the strings individually.

Comment: Then it's simply `strlist2.get(y)` in your loop, and get rid of the forst loop with the iterator, you only need one, see my edit.